# How to automatically run a python application on boot to desktop?

Tags: python, boot

I am running raspbian and my pi boots straight to desktop. I am wondering how I could schedule a script to run at boot to desktop and not at power-on.

Answer (score 1):

Did exactly the same in my Raspberry PI. Add the command to run your application to `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` as it follows:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash

@python /home/pi/python_cool_stuff/yourscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You use two ways here :

- using rc.local to shell-scripted desktop detection and running your script at the right time
- using your desktop environment's autorun capabilities. `startx` script can utilize `.xinitrc` scripts by auto-including and executing them. In case that you need to exec your script *after/inside* not just a GUI, but a display manager - read its man page. The default `LXDM` is well-documented [here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-autostart-apps-in-rasbian-lxde-desktop/). Basically you'll just use a `.desktop` file

Answer (score 0):

I use this for a reboot button.

> sudo nano /etc/rc.local

Then, above the last line:

> python /home/pi/scripts/reboot.py &

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` is executed when the OS is starting, the `/home/user/.bashrc` is executed when a user login.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same requirement. I found the best way was using cron. 
Best thing about cron is you do not need to login and you can fully control the process, how many time to run, when to run etc..

[See this Link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md)